# How to parse an object from Streambuilder snapshot

Tags: dart, flutter, reactive-programming, rxdart

My application is using (BLOC) RxDart and Streams to pass information around and dynamically build Widgets.

However, if it pass a simple PODO ( Plain old dart object ) into the stream I have trouble parsing it using the StreamBuilder widget.

I can output it toString and it prints 'Instance of object' however if I can't seem to drill any deeper into the object details.

**Adding to the stream controller**

```
final _streamController = BehaviorSubject<Object>();
Function(Object) get addObjectToStream => _streamController.sink.add;
```

**Using a validator to add to stream**

```
  final addToStream = StreamTransformer<Object, Object>.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (device, sink) {
      sink.add(device);
    }
  );
```

**Consuming the Stream**

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: bloc.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) { 
                  return Text('${snapshot.data.toString()}'); //This works 'instance of Object'
                } else {
                  return Text('No data to be displayed');
                }

              }),
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i dont see any `PODO` in your code - everywhere you use [Objects](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/Object-class.html)

Comment: It's the Object, I just generically named it. It was Device which just had a string value in it for id.

Comment: so use `Object object = snapshot.data;`

Comment: @pskink That worked. For some reason I thought the Snapshot would be the same Object that was passed into the stream. I didn't realise you need to instantiate a new object based of it. Seems simple now. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: sure, your welcome